# Receive KVO notifications for all property and changes recursively at top level

Tags: key-value-observing, reactive-cocoa

If I have the following data model:

```
Model
    - subModels (NSMutableArray * of type SubModel)

SubModel
    - text
    - createdAt
```

is it possible to use KVO to observe changes on the parent `Model` class and still receive changes notifications for properties on relationship models?

Using `ReactiveCocoa`, what I'm trying to accomplish would look something like this:

```
self.model = [Model new];
self.model.subModels = [NSMutableArray array];
SubModel *subModelOne = [SubModel new];
[self.model mutableArrayValueForKeyPath:@"subModels"] addObject:subModelOne];
[RACObserve(self, model) subscribeNext:^(id next){
     NSLog(@"%@", next);
}];
subModelOne.text = @"Lollipop, lollipop, oh lolli lolli lolli lollipop!";
```

What I want to happen is I would get a next event from initializing `model.subModels` to an empty array, one from adding a sub model to the relationship, and finally one from setting `subModelOne.text`. Essentially I want all subproperties, submodels, etc, KVO notifications to propagate up the chain but I'm not sure how to accomplish that task.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want a KVO answer and not a RAC one?

Comment: RAC would be preferable. I found this: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1195, I haven't had a chance to look at/evaluate it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last paragraph in your question is the key to the solution:

> What I want to happen is I would get a next event from initializing model.subModels to an empty array...

So we'll have one signal watching the `subModels` property on `model`.

> one from adding a sub model to the relationship,

Not sure if you can do this specifically. With KVO, when you observe a property you're observing changes to that property, so when you observe a property that is an `NSMutableArray` object, you won't receive notifications until *you change the object*, by which I mean: assign a new array to that property. Adding or removing items from the array don't count as "changing the property". So the ideal way to do this would be to use an immutable array, when you need to change the items, create a new `NSArray` as needed and assign it to the property. Then you can observe it. You're using the `mutableArrayValueForKey:`, which apparently makes the `count` property KVO-compliant. I've never used it so I'm not sure atm. Which option to go with is up to you.

> and finally one from setting subModelOne.text.

Our last signal will be watching the `text` property of the `subModel`.

If you want a single signal that sends you events for all these changes, you use `combineLatest:reduce:`:

```
RACSignal* subModelsSignal = [RACObserve(self.model, subModels) startWith:self.model.subModels];
RACSignal* textSignal = [RACObserve(subModel, text) startWith:subModel.text];
...
NSArray* allSignalsYouWantCombined = @[subModelsSignal, textSignal, ... ];
RACSignal* combined = [RACSignal combineLatest:allSignalsYouWantCombined reduce:^(NSArray* subModels, text, ...) { ... }];
```